# SSIS date transformation

Tags: ssis

i have a flat file with a date column in the format DD-MMM-YY i want to load this column to my DB with format YYYY-MM-DD using visual studio my problem is when i'm trying to create a Derived Column to make the data transformation i get an erro
here is the code i'm trying to use on SSIS

```
"20" + SUBSTRING([Data Chiusura Deroga],8,2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)(FINDSTRING("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",SUBSTRING([Data Chiusura Deroga],4,3),1) / 3 + 1),2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Data Chiusura Deroga],1,2)
```

anyway to make it work ?

i tried to  convert my column into NVARCHAR and then try the transformation it worked but it gives me the month always 01

Answer (score 0):

What you've provided works, for the correct data.

Given an input query like this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    VALUES
        ('11-Jan-01')
    ,   ('12-Feb-02')
    ,   ('13-Mar-03')
    ,   ('14-Apr-04')
    ,   ('15-May-05')
    ,   ('16-Jun-06')
    ,   ('17-Jul-07')
    ,   ('18-Aug-08')
    ,   ('19-Sep-09')
    ,   ('20-Oct-10')
    ,   ('21-Nov-11')
    ,   ('22-Dec-12')
) AS D([Data Chiusura Deroga]);
```

Your expression will generate the expected values. However, FINDSTRING is case sensitive so adding "23-DEC-13" will result in a value of 2013-01-23.

Debugging complex expressions is challenging so I take an approach of splitting  them up into multiple steps so you can add a data viewer/data tap to a dataflow  and compare inputs to outputs. Plus, adding additional columns to your data flow doesn't really hurt you performance-wise and there is no requirement to land all the data you generate in a data flow.

Add a Derived Column Transformation, "DER Anno di chiusura". This will add a column with our year value

- Derived Column Name "Anno"
- Expression `"20" + RIGHT([Data Chiusura Deroga],2)`

Add a Derived Column Transformation, "DER Giorno di chiusura". This will slice out the day.

- Derived Column Name "Giorno"
- `SUBSTRING([Data Chiusura Deroga],1,2)`

Next, we need to deal with the month. I honestly don't understand *how* the logic you have works, but it does work for the ideal case but does not when the case does not match so we'll simply transform all the values to their UPPER case---and also apply that same uppercasing to the arguments of FINDSTRING. Add a Derived Column Transformation, "DER Mese di chiusura". This will slice out the month regardless of casing

- Column named "Mesi"
- `RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)(FINDSTRING("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC",UPPER(SUBSTRING([Data Chiusura Deroga],4,3)),1) / 3 + 1),2)`

Now that we have the 3 items we need, it's a matter of making our final column which concatenates them together. Add "DER Data Chiusura"

- Column named "DataChiusura"
- Expression `[Anno] + "-" + [Mesi] + "-" + [Giorno]`

Here you can see our original value, the intermediate columns along the way plus the final value. The "ref" column is the reference implementation you provided and you can see the case where it calculates the wrong month due to case sensitivity.

[image]